# Highcharts clientside export plugin. TypeError 'C is undefined'

Tags: canvas, highcharts, typeerror, jspdf

There is a new plugin available from Highcharts to allow for client side rendering of charts.

[Clientside Exporting](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/37/highcharts-export-clientside)

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pscjzhe4/1/) for it seems to work flawlessly, but I’m having some trouble replicating the fiddle on my server. Specifically, I get a ‘TypeError: c is undefined’ message in my Firebug console window.

I have setup my page in the following way …

```
<!-- jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css"/>

<!-- HighCharts -->  
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<!-- Highcharts Exporting Dependencies --> 
<script src="//a----.github.io/highcharts-export-clientside/bower_components/export-csv/export-csv.js"></script>        

<!—Uncommenting will produce the TypeError ‘C is undefined’ -->                                                               
<!-- <script src="//a----.github.io/highcharts-export-clientside/bower_components/highcharts/modules/canvas-tools.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="//a----.github.io/highcharts-export-clientside/bower_components/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>  -->

<!-- Export Client-Side module -->
<script src="//a----.github.io/highcharts-export-clientside/bower_components/highcharts-export-clientside/highcharts-export-clientside.js"></script>
```

If I remove or comment out everything other than ‘export-csv.js’ within the ‘Highcharts Exporting Dependencies’ section. I can render a chart as an SVG and download the csv/xls file without any issues at all. However, as soon as I enable canvas-tools or jspdf, I get the TypeError mentioned earlier.

Initially, I thought perhaps it was somehting related to the files being accessed via a github account. But moving canvas-tools and jspdf to a directory local to my server still results in the TypeError.

May I ask for some pointers, please? I don’t know javascript very well at all and I’m struggling to identify what I have done wrong with this plugin.

I guess I’m missing some other dependancy for using canvas-tools and jspdf.

Answer (score 1):

The Type C Error shown in my browser (FireFox) turned out to be a non issue. After a little more diagnosis, I noticed the issue of failing to export a chart locally using the client side rendering plugin was because I had added an image to the chart ... think of a watermark image.

Removing the image from the chart allowed it to be rendered client side, even with the Type C Error in the browser console.

After posting a question in the HighCharts forum, it was suggested that I make the plugin author aware and open a ticket on Github. Which I did.

The author responded within a few hours and has since fixed this issue. A new fiddle that uses client side rendering (with an embedded image) can be seen here ...

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/xa8wke0b/4/`
```

As I seem to be getting an awful lot of 'Oops, your SVG is too big' messages from the HighCharts export server, I think this is going to prove to be an extremely useful plugin.